# Sending multiple multipart ZMQ PUB messages in parallel

Tags: zeromq

What is the preferred pattern for this? Multiple contexts? Waiting until all patterns for the message are assembled and sending them synchronized?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution:

- Each sender connects to an IPC `PUSH` socket and writes multipart messages to it. When it's done, it closes the socket.
- A dedicated thread receives on the opposite IPC `PULL` socket and writes the messages, part-by-part, into one TCP `PUB` socket.